# How to mixed-swap values in SQL?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas

I've a data frame in python 3, got from a database, that looks like the following:

```
     col_A      col_B
0    Mas34         10
1    Mer21         32
2   Mas$34         10
```

col_A is string type (PRIMARY KEY also) and col_B is int type. I want to find a SQL query that allows me to swap that values, getting a result like the following:

```
     col_A      col_B
0    Mer21         32
1    Mas34         10
2   Mer$21         32
```

If row 2 doesn't exist, the query will be like that:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET col_A =
  (case when col_A = 'Mas34' then 'Mer21' else 'Mas34' end),
SET col_B =
  (case when col_A = 10 then 32 else 10 end)
WHERE id_muestra in ('Mas34', 'Mer21')
```

However, I don't know if it's possible to do what I want with a simply query, or more previous python code is needed.

Thanks you very much in advance!

Comment: Tables in sql are sets of rows. There is no order unless you specify it in an order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

How about this?

```
update t
    set col_B = (case when col_B = 1 then 2 else 1 end);
```

Or, more simply:

```
update t
    set col_B = 2 - col_B;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gordon. I'm going to modify my example, because 1 and 2 are just examples, and what I want is swap the whole values.